# Is it possible to disable a GtkNotebook tab (like set_sensitive(*tab*, false)) in GTK+ 2.24?

Tags: user-interface, tabs, gtk, disabled-control, sensitive-data

I have searched on the internet but didn't reach any conclusion.
This feature feels "natural" in the GUI, that's why I'm asking here despite having found nothing on the issue.
I already know that if I hide the top widget of the notebook page, the tab disappears, but that's not what I'm looking for. What I really wanted was for the tab to not be sensitive, just like `gtk_widget_set_sensitive(GTK_WIDGET(notebook_tab), false);`
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to deactive a tab in a notebook. Commonly we just hide that tab if it is useless in current context.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old. But I just go trough the same issue. I solved it by setting sensitive to false for the icon I have in my tab.

Of course, same can work for label...

Comment: This is false. Setting a tab child (like GtkLabel) to insensitive does not disable the tab.